# ¿Cómo validar que obtuve en un archivo de php atreves de AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

encontré un código en internet que estoy intento implementar en un proyecto, es sobre una búsqueda en tiempo real con JQuery, AJAX y PHP. Lo eh modificado a mi forma pero no logro entender la lógica del script después que se ejecuta el ajax.
La lógica dicta que mientras no obtiene un resultado en concreto me mostrara un error pero si encuentra algo en concreto me muestra el resultado, la pregunta es como funciona o como obtengo un valor en la parte que dice: if(data.status == 1) para que cuando tenga un resultado con éxito me muestre lo que hay dentro de ese if. Por el momento siempre me marca error pero mediante el inspector red de mi navegador ya estoy trayendo datos.

```
            <div class="wrap-input100 rs1-wrap-input100 validate-input">

                <span class="label-input100">Patrocinador*</span>

                <div class="mId1">
                    <span class="input-group-addon mId2" style="display:none;"></span>

                    <input type="text" class="input100" id="patrocinador" name="patrocinador" placeholder="Ingresa la CURP/Cedula de tu patrocinador" maxlength="18">

                </div>
                <p class="help-block mName"></p>

            </div>

$("#patrocinador").keyup('on', function() {
    var rf = $("#patrocinador").val();
    if (rf != '') {
        $('.mId1').addClass('input-group');
        $('.mId2').show();
        $('.mId2').html('<img style="height: 20px;" src="images/ajax-loader.gif">');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_patrocinador.php?curp=' + rf,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    $('.mName').html('<span style="color:green;">Patrocinador : ' + data + '</span>');
                    $('.mId2').html('<img style="height: 20px;" src="images/green_checkmark.jpg">');
                } else {
                    $('.mName').html('<span style="color:red;">Patrocinador Desconocido</span>');
                    $('.mId2').html('<img style="height: 20px;" src="images/cross_mark.jpg">');
                }
            },
        });
    } else {
        $('.mId1').removeClass('input-group');
        $('.mId2').hide();
        $('.mName').html('');
    }
});
```

-------------------------------------ARCHIVO DONDE HAGO LA CONSULTA A LA BD-------------------

```
    <?php

require_once('db.php');
require_once('conexion.php');

$curp = $_GET['curp'];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE curp = '". $curp ."' ");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$nombre = $resultado["name"];
$a_p = $resultado["a_p"];
$a_m = $resultado["a_m"];

echo $a_p . " " . $a_m . " " . $nombre; 
?>
```

Comment: No estás devolviendo la variable data por ningún lado, tendrías que hacer un return y cargar la variable para recogerla después en la vista mediante ajax, con el echo no devuelves nada  si no que muestras en vista

Comment: Ok gracias, una ultima duda son muy princípiate con JS y JQuery, como cargo la variable para poder recogerla como dices?

Comment: Tal como te ha dicho, debes devolverla (`return`) desde php, no ***imprimas***, ***devuelve***

Comment: Lo eh puesto como me han dicho: $resultado = $a_p . " " . $a_m . " " . $nombre; return $resultado;

Pero aun no logro visualizar nada en el resultado del AJAX me sigue marcado que no hay nada, la consulta hacia la base esta bien junto con le parametro que le estoy pasado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto que tambien puedes hacerlo por echo

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1,));
```

si quieres pasar todos los parametros  seria así:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 1, 'nombre' => $nombre, 'ap'=>$a_p));
```

Y para recuperarlos en ajax seria así

```
success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 1) {
            
            alert(data.nombre);

            alert(data.ap)
               
            } else {
               
            }
```

Comment: lo del alert es un ejemplo para que te  muestre mediante un alert el valor devuelto despues con ese valor peudes hacer lo que tu necesites

Comment: Hola si me sirvió, no funcionaba xq en el ajax no había puesto el tipo de dato: dataType: 'JSON'

Gracias